# difference between socket.PF_PACKET and socket.AF_INET in python

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7, python-3.x

i just want to know that in python socket programming, when to use socket_PF_PACKET and when to use socket.AF_INET, what are difference between both of them?

Comment: Read more about [sockets](http://swoolley.org/man.cgi/2/socket) and you'll find out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `AF_INET` if you want to communicate using Internet protocols: TCP or UDP.  This is by far the most common choice, and almost certainly what you want.

Use `PF_PACKET` if you want to send and receive messages at the most basic level, below the Internet protocol layer, for example because you are implementing the protocol yourself.  Your process must run as root (or with a special capability) to use `PF_PACKET`.  This is a very advanced option.  If you have to ask this question, you want `AF_INET`, not `PF_PACKET`.

Comment: ok got it ,thanks. i am creating a ICMP packet and want to send it on my LAN. when i use AF_INET it's working, but wen i use PF_PACKET that shows an error in 'sendto' like... "error- sendto(packet, (destination, 0)) ... no such device" ....

Comment: Are you saying, that socket created in PF_PACKET domain, i dont need to attach L4 and L3 layer headers to packet, just L2 layer header is suffice ?
It means, such packets are used to send pkt only to directly connected next hop ?

Comment: @Radhe Tripathi,you want to use bind before sending packets...Something like s.bind(("eth0",socket.htons(0x0800)))  #eth0 is your interface name ,you can find it on ifconfig